# What's the recommended way of renaming a project in pypi?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, distutils

I want people that know of the old name to be directed to the new name.

For the pypi website, it's easy to upload a package with a README linking to the new package.

I'm not sure what's the best way to handle people using pip to install it. I assume it might be possible to show an error on `pip install old_name`, looking around it seems to be possible using [cmdclass](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/extending.html) in setup.py and maybe throwing an exception in the right place  but the documentation around it is scarce to put it mildly.

So I was wondering if anyone is aware of proper built-in systems for this, or common practices to handle this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare the new package a dependency of the old. See for example how [scikit-learn](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) does it: the old package [sklearn](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) declares in its `setup.py`:

```
install_requires=['scikit-learn'],
```

Thus everyone who does `pip install sklearn` automatically gets `scikit-learn`.

Comment: `sklearn` isn't "the old version". It's a thing someone seems to have put up for convenience, to stop bad guys from taking the name, and/or to get people to stop complaining when `pip install sklearn` fails. The actual `scikit-learn` has a much longer activity history.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I used it only for an example. A small well-known example.

Answer (score 3):

pypi-rename worked perfectly for me. It automates the process of making a README and redirecting users to the new package.

https://github.com/simonw/pypi-rename