# How can I rename my project on PyPI to fix its capitalization?

Tags: python, pypi, distutils, python-poetry

My PyPI project has an error in its name. Concretely, it has the wrong capitalization. So, e.g., instead of `project` I used the name `Project`.

How can I change the name on PyPI to fix this mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to change the name of a project depends on what kind of change is made:

##### A) Changing the capitalization

If only the capitalization is wrong, simply fix it in your project's `pyproject.toml`, update the version with a [post release signifier](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#post-release-separators), rebuild, and publish again.

##### B) Renaming the project

Renaming projects in the web interface is not supported. Instead, you need to publish the project again, under a different name. This will create a new project with the correct name, associated to your account. Contrary to A), you do not need to increment the project version, otherwise the steps are identical.

Note: You may want to explicitly mark the old package name as obsolete if the name was in use for a longer time. See the [recommended way to rename a package on PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61363534/5712053) and the [pypi-rename cookiecutter template](https://github.com/simonw/pypi-rename).